# Find the median of each row of a 2 dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, multidimensional-array, median

I am trying to find the median of each row of a 2 dimensional array. This is what I have tried so far but I cannot get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def median_rows(list):            
    for lineindex in range(len(Matrix)):
        sorted(Matrix[lineindex])

        mid_upper = ((len(Matrix[lineindex]))/2
        mid_lower = ((len(Matrix[lineindex])+1)/2
        if len(Matrix[lineindex])%2 == 0:
            #have to take avg of middle two
            median = (Matrix[mid_lower] + Matrix[mid_upper])/2.0
            print "The median is %f" %median
       else:
            median = srtd[mid]  
            print "The median is %d" %median


median_rows(Matrix)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep things simple, use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/)'s [`median`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.median.html):

```
matrix = numpy.array(zip(range(10), [x+1 for x in range(10)])).T
# array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
#        [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10]])
np.median(matrix, axis=1) # array([ 4.5,  5.5])
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the obvious variable naming errors: `Matrix` is not defined.  You probably meant `list`, or you meant to name the function argument as `Matrix`. Btw `list` is not a good variable name to have, as there is Python data type `list`.  Also `Matrix` isn't a good name either, as it's good practice to have variable names lowercase.  Also, `srtd` is not defined.

Once you correct the naming errors, then the next problem is `sorted(xyz)` does not modify `xyz`, but returns a sorted copy of `xyz`.  So you need to assign it to something.  Well, don't assign it back to `Matrix[lineindex]`, because then the function will have the undesirable side effect of changing the input matrix passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out a bit. As @Rishi said, there were a lot of variable name issues.

```
def median_rows(matrix):
    for line in matrix:  # line is each row of the matrix
        sorted_line = sorted(line)  # have to set the sorted line to a variable
        mid_point = len(sorted_line) / 2  # only need to do one, because we know the upper index will always be the one after the midpoint
        if len(line) % 2 == 0:
            # have to take avg of middle two
            median = (sorted_line[mid_point] + sorted_line[mid_point + 1]) / 2.0
            print "The median is %f" % median  
        else:
            median = line[mid_point]
            print "The median is %d" % median

matrix = [[1,2,3,5],[1,2,3,7]]

median_rows(matrix)
```