# Identification of rows containing column median in numpy matrix of cum percentiles

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean, median

Consider the matrix `quantiles` that's a subset `[:8,:3,0]` of a 3D matrix with shape `(10,355,8)`.

```
quantiles = np.array([
       [ 1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.63763978,  0.61848863,  0.75348137],
       [ 0.43439645,  0.42485407,  0.5341457 ],
       [ 0.22682343,  0.18878366,  0.25253915],
       [ 0.16229408,  0.12541476,  0.15263742],
       [ 0.12306046,  0.10372971,  0.09832783],
       [ 0.09271845,  0.08209844,  0.05982584],
       [ 0.06363636,  0.05471266,  0.03855727]])
```

I want a boolean output of the same shape as the `quantiles` matrix where `True` marks the row in which the median is located:

```
In [21]: medians
Out[21]:
array([[False, False, False],
       [ True, True,  False],
       [False,  False, True],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

To achieve this, I have the following algorithm in mind:

1) Identify the entries that are greater than `.5`:

```
In [22]: quantiles>.5
Out[22]:
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

2) Considering only the values subset by the `quantiles>.5` operation, mark the row that minimizes the `np.abs` distance between the entry and `.5`. Torturing the terminology a bit, I wish to intersect the two matrices of `np.argmin(np.abs(quantiles-.5),axis=0)` and `quantiles>.5` to get the above result. However, I cannot for my life figure out a way to perform the `np.argmin` on the subset and retain the shape of the `quantile` matrix.

PS. Yes, there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33658580/find-the-median-of-each-row-of-a-2-dimensional-array-in-python) but it doesn't implement my algorithm which could be, I think, more efficient on a larger scale

Comment: Would each column be sorted in descending order in the input?

Comment: @Divakar hi mate, sorry I didn't get to your question earlier. There's no sorting of any kind. Actually, maintaining alignment is integral to subsequent operations(not shown here)

Answer (score 1):

Bumping into the old `mask` operation in `Numpy`, I found the following solution

```
#mask quantities that are less than .5
masked_quantiles = ma.masked_where(quantiles<.5,quantiles)

#identify the minimum in column of the masked array
median_idx = np.where(masked_quantiles == masked_quantiles.min(axis=0))

#make a matrix of all False values
median_mat = np.zeros(quantiles.shape, dtype=bool)

#assign True value to corresponding rows
In [86]: median_mat[medians] = True

In [87]: median_mat
Out[87]:
array([[False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

## Update: comparison of my answer to that of Divakar's:

I ran two comparisons, one on the sample 2D matrix provided for this question and one on my 3D `(10,380,8)` dataset (not large data by any means).

#### Sample dataset:

My code

```
%%timeit
masked_quantiles = ma.masked_where(quantiles<=.5,quantiles)
median_idx = masked_quantiles.argmin(0)

10000 loops, best of 3: 65.1 µs per loop
```

Divakar's code

```
%%timeit
mask1 = quantiles<=0.5
min_idx = (quantiles+mask1).argmin(0)

The slowest run took 17.49 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.92 µs per loop
```

#### Full dataset

My code:

```
%%timeit
masked_quantiles = ma.masked_where(quantiles<=.5,quantiles)
median_idx = masked_quantiles.argmin(0)

1000 loops, best of 3: 490 µs per loop
```

Divakar's code:

```
%%timeit
mask1 = quantiles<=0.5
min_idx = (quantiles+mask1).argmin(0)

10000 loops, best of 3: 172 µs per loop
```

#### Conclusion:

Divakar's answer seems about 3-12 times faster than mine. I presume that the `np.ma.where` masking operation takes longer than matrix addition. However, the addition operation needs to be stored whereas masking may be more efficient on larger datasets. I wonder how it would compare on something that doesn't or nearly doesn't fit into memory.

Comment: You don't need that `np.abs()` there I think as I would think quantiles would always be positive?

Comment: @Divakar, I removed it, it gave a little boost. But yea, as I noted in my answer, I wonder how masking versus addition scales to larger matrixes -not that it's important at this point

Comment: If you are talking about masking as in using numpy masked arrays, I haven't dealt with them much. Also, I haven't really noticed posts with those winning over simply using numpy boolean arrays. If you are concerned about memory usage, I have an alternative in mind, will update soon in my post.

Comment: Updated with another approach.

Answer (score 1):

### Approach #1

Here's an approach using [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and some masking trick -

```
# Mask of quantiles lesser than or equal to 0.5 to select the invalid ones
mask1 = quantiles<=0.5

# Since we are dealing with quantiles, the elems won't be > 1, 
# which can be leveraged here as we will add 1s to invalid elems, and 
# then look for argmin across each col
min_idx = (np.abs(quantiles-0.5)+mask1).argmin(0)

# Let some broadcasting magic happen here!
out = min_idx == np.arange(quantiles.shape[0])[:,None]
```

**Step-by-step run**

1) Input :

```
In [37]: quantiles
Out[37]: 
array([[ 1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.63763978,  0.61848863,  0.75348137],
       [ 0.43439645,  0.42485407,  0.5341457 ],
       [ 0.22682343,  0.18878366,  0.25253915],
       [ 0.16229408,  0.12541476,  0.15263742],
       [ 0.12306046,  0.10372971,  0.09832783],
       [ 0.09271845,  0.08209844,  0.05982584],
       [ 0.06363636,  0.05471266,  0.03855727]])
```

2) Run the code :

```
In [38]: mask1 = quantiles<=0.5
    ...: min_idx = (np.abs(quantiles-0.5)+mask1).argmin(0)
    ...: out = min_idx == np.arange(quantiles.shape[0])[:,None]
    ...:
```

3) Analyze output at each step :

```
In [39]: mask1
Out[39]: 
array([[False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [40]: np.abs(quantiles-0.5)+mask1
Out[40]: 
array([[ 0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.5       ],
       [ 0.13763978,  0.11848863,  0.25348137],
       [ 1.06560355,  1.07514593,  0.0341457 ],
       [ 1.27317657,  1.31121634,  1.24746085],
       [ 1.33770592,  1.37458524,  1.34736258],
       [ 1.37693954,  1.39627029,  1.40167217],
       [ 1.40728155,  1.41790156,  1.44017416],
       [ 1.43636364,  1.44528734,  1.46144273]])

In [41]: (np.abs(quantiles-0.5)+mask1).argmin(0)
Out[41]: array([1, 1, 2])

In [42]: min_idx == np.arange(quantiles.shape[0])[:,None]
Out[42]: 
array([[False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

**Performance boost** : Following the comments, it seems to get min_idx, we can just do :

```
min_idx = (quantiles+mask1).argmin(0)
```

### Approach #2

This is focused on memory efficiency.

```
# Mask of quantiles greater than 0.5 to select the valid ones
mask = quantiles>0.5

# Select valid elems
vals = quantiles.T[mask.T]

# Get vald count per col
count = mask.sum(0)

# Get the min val per col given the mask
minval = np.minimum.reduceat(vals,np.append(0,count[:-1].cumsum()))

# Get final boolean array by just comparing the min vals across each col
out = np.isclose(quantiles,minval)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, the implicit intersection of the difference and `mask1` is very clever! Also, the last line in flattening the array and comparing the indices is quite cool too. Disregarding the very last step, do you think there are efficiency gains over my answer?

Comment: @GeneBurinsky Hmm it's hard to tell really. Can you time these on your actual large dataset?

Comment: note that you do not have to subtract `.5` from `quantiles` matrix, the elimination of anything less than `.5` and adding 1 (or intersection in my answer) already makes sure we're finding the closest element to .5 from above in each column

Comment: @GeneBurinsky Ah awesome! So, you can just do : `(quantiles+mask1).argmin(0)`!

Comment: the second option is quite interesting but in my timings it basically doesn't do better than `np.ma.where` and it doesn't generalize to higher dimensional arrays. It does introduce a few functions I wasn't aware of such as `reduceat`.

Comment: @GeneBurinsky Yeah, that second approach isn't necessarily meant for performance, it's focused more on memory efficiency.